# Can I emit object to stream with only one updated field?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have one Behavior Subject that is a private field in my service

```
private data = new BehaviorSubject<Email>({
    body: '',
    email: ''
});
```

Can I create method for updating just one field of Email object and emitting it to stream? Something like this?

```
setBody(inputBody: string) {
    this.data.next({body: inputBody});
}
```

The problem here is I need to leave other field unchanged. Is it possible?
Maybe it's possible to create one 'generic' method for updating any field by its name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must get current value of BehaviorSubject and then update your specific property

```
setBody(inputBody: string) {
    const content = this.data.getValue()
    this.data.next({...content, body: inputBody});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### The Generic Field Setter:

#### #1 Using Behaviour Subject's `.getValue()`

```js
setField(field: string, payLoad: any) {
  this.data.next({
    ...this.data.getValue(), 
    [field]: payLoad
  });
}
```

#### #2 Using any observable's next value

Here, `this.data` doesn't need to be a `BehaviorSubject`.

```js
setField(field: string, payLoad: any) {
  this.data.pipe(
    take(1),
    map(curr => ({...curr, [field]: payLoad}))
  ).subscribe(this.data.next.bind(this.data));
}
```